# How to send the image taken with device camera as it is to server without losing its quality, width and height?

Tags: android, image, rest, resolution

I am taking the picture and saving it in sdcard. And later some time I am saving the same picture to server by creating a file like the following.

```
            ByteArrayOutputStream boas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, boas);

            resizeBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG  ,100, boas);

            byte[] b = boas.toByteArray();
```

The Byte array I am sending to the server.

But image quality and size is saving incorrect. If the resolution is 1200 X 1600 instead 320 * 240 is saving in server.

Answer (score 0):

How are you saving your picture when it is taken? If you don't supply a URI you will only get a low resolution thumbnail in return.

EDIT: Code how to get full image from camera, I'm only guessing your problem right now;

```
   Intent in = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
   File out = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
   String fileName="image.png"; 
   out = new File(out, fileName); 
   in.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(out)); 
   startActivityForResult(in);
```

Comment: I am creating the camera with surface view and launching the camera to take the pictures. and giving the path as creating directory in getExternalStoreageDirectory() with  foldername.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted it only shows that you make a from a bitmap a PNG then a JPG with 0% dropping in quality.